# Undo effects of running ntfsfix (ntfs-3g) on a Windows exfat partition

Tags: partition, ntfs, ntfs-3g

Using Linux I was trying to access an exfat partition that was created using the partition tool in Windows. Due to some improper shutdown issue I was not allowed access.

Then I took the brilliant decision of running `ntfsfix` on it

```
mint@mint:~$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda9
Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
The alternate bootsector is usable
Rewriting the bootsector
The boot sector has been rewritten
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x47aac24e  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 7255  usa_count: 20242: Invalid argument
Record 0 has no FILE magic (0x47aac24e)
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

After this the partition in question, sda9, was being shown as NTFS. It was exfat before this step.

[image: gparted screenshot]

I did run `chkdsk` on the partition from Windows and got

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>chkdsk f:
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Unable to determine volume version and state.  CHKDSK aborted.
```

I got access to another exfat partition(sda5) that was not put through `ntfsfix` simply by accessing the drive from a Windows machine but the newly NTFS partition wont open saying the 'partition is corrupted and unreadable'

So I feel marking the partition as exfat however ntfs-3g marked the partition as NTFS will give me back access to my drive.

Are there any non-destructive things I can try?
My top priority is to save the data on this disk.

- [`sgdisk` print of partition and disk](https://pastebin.com/raw/EBE0nGWx)
- [`fdisk -l` before `ntfsfix`](https://pastebin.com/ZBJDrMQd)

Comment: Hey man, had you saved your data? I am in same situation here, help would be appreciated.